# Susy - change number of columns on a fluid container

Tags: sass, breakpoints, fluid-layout, susy-compass

I have a **div.article** that is 2 columns wide on a 8 columns layout.

At a breakpoint which increases the layout to 12 columns, I'd like to have my **div.article** still beeing 2 columns wide.

*Note that the column width is not fixed due to the fluid container.*

The issue is that **div.article** keeps its original width when my layout (and my column width) changes. Its width remains as it was 2 "old" columns wide.

In order to fix that, I must have a markup like this :

```
.article {
    @include span-columns(2); // original size
    @include at-breakpoint($mobile_portrait) {
        @include span-columns(2); // I must add this so its new width is large as 2 columns of the new layout
    }
}
```

Is there any way to prevent repetitive markup like this on a fluid grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. It's not a matter of fluid design.

What you're doing is called a "magic grid" in Susy vocabulary. The grid has different number of columns for different screen sizes.

To make it work, CSS should contain styles for both small and large screen layouts. What you do here is providing them. Note that when `span-columns` is invoked from inside `at-breakpoint`, it produces different values.

So that's the appropriate way to do it. You should feel comfortable with that code.

Have a look at Susy's magic grid demo: http://susy.oddbird.net/demos/magic/#demo-breakpoints